# wrap_content on imageView using Picasso

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso

I have a social media and I want to add the height of the image on the post to `wrap_content`, but when i retrieve the images of the Firebase and display them on `recycler view` the image is not displayed with `wrap_content`. Also I'm using Picasso to set the image.

**the part of code when I'm using to set the image (with Picasso):**

```
         Picasso.get()
                .load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.m1)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.postImg);
```

**post_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="george the developer"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.038"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_contenta\"
            android:src="@drawable/m1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/post_username" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_username"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/like_emoji_before" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/like_counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/post_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/likeBtn"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/post_username"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: try to remove `.centerCrop()`

Comment: @Zain now it shows all the image but the height is kind
cramped

Comment: also remove `fit()` and add `android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"` into the `ImageView` in layout ..

Comment: @Zain you are the best . Please make a full reply to mark it as the awnser 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `centerCrop()` to avoid cropping the image, also remove `fit()` as it tries to calculate an appropriate image size, although you need its full size.

So now we have:

```
     Picasso.get()
            .load(postList.get(position).getImgUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.m1)
            .into(holder.postImg);
```

And for the `ImageView`: add the below couple of attributes to make sure the image has the full size.

```
    <ImageView
        ...
         android:scaleType="fitStart"    
         android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Zain, I needed this, although things got redacted on April fool's day, it is top secret.